# QDomNode to html

Tags: c++, qt, dom, stream

I have `QDomNode` object and I need to get html representation of data inside it. I found a method [QDomNode::save( QTextStream & str, int indent )](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdomnode.html#save):

> Writes the XML representation of the node and all its children to the
>   stream str. This function uses indent as the amount of space to indent
>   the node.

I tried to use it this way:

```
QDomNode table = ...;

QString *htmlTable;
QTextStream stream(htmlTable);

table.save(stream, 2);
qDebug() << htmlTable;
```

QDebug returns a pointer. And in other cases program fails. I think I use `QTextStream` wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `qDebug() << *htmlTable;` ?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't reserved memory for your QString.

```
QString htmlTable;
QTextStream stream(&htmlTable);
table.save(stream, 2);
```

should work, but i haven't tested it.